# Hub RFID Arduino + WIFI

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-yun, wifi, rfid

I will start an Arduino project and its main requirement is that some RFID readers (at most 6 readers) be connected and controled by the arduino board.

I do not have a strong background in eletronics, and therefore I do not have any idea in how to start it. Is it possible to connect more than one RFID reader to an Arduino board? If it is possible, which reader is the best for this porpouse?

Another requirement of this project is the need to send the data collected by each RFID reader to a PC server through WIFI. For this what is better to use, an Arduino UNO with a WIFI shield or an Arduino YUN? What is better and why?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Which RFID reader will you use? Depending on model a different amount of pins are used (from 1 to 3 at least). So if you choose a reader that only requires 1 pin you might be able to connect all 6 to one arduino. Another question is how far apart these should be? If very far it might not be feasable anyways, and easier to use multiple arduinis... As you say that each reader should send its data over wifi. Then instead of putting cables for each RFID to a central Arduino, just put down Ethernet cable and use a standard Ethernet module and multiple arduinis to send the data to a PC.

Comment: I have not decided yet which RFID reader I will use. Can you sugest anyone? The idea is build a smart table that can recognize tagged objets over it, thus I think that the distance is not more than 1 meter between each reader and the Arduino. If required more than one Arduino the project is not be feasible. WIFI is a primary requirement, the client do not want data cables from table to a PC, all data collected by the RFID reader must be sent through WIFI.

Comment: Ok, then it wouldnt be a problem to connect multiple rfid readers to one arduino I guess, if the library allows this. I cannot recommend any reader, as I have just bought a simple one from ebay, but havent tried it yet, so I really cant comment on functionality either. I'll have to get back to you when I have tried this out...